# Custom button is not showing correctly in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I'm learning to develop iOS apps in XCode.
I've created simple custom button (subclass of UIButton) that should have red background and green text. When running the app in iOS simulator, everything is ok. But in interface builder other colors (specified in interface builder) are used. Test project is available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/ro7i4omdbpwapi0/testapp%20%282%29.zip?dl=0. Can somebody help?

Here is source code of custom UIbutton class:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class DefaultButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        //setBackgroundImage(UIImage.createGradient(colors:  [ UIColor.defaultGradientStartColor, UIColor.defaultGradientEndColor ], startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)), for: .normal)
        //layer.cornerRadius = 50
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @the4kman have you downloaded attached project? it's minimal example with one custom button class that doesn't render in IB.

Comment: You should include the code that reproduces the issue in the question itself.

Comment: @the4kman it seems that it's much simpler just to run attached project to see the problem. But ok, I'll include source code of DefaultButton class in the post

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour described in you answer is correct; but i think you mixes two different things.

Basically, if you want to tint your button title, and your button background, you have to use the fields availables in interface builder. You have some nice properties to set up these things easely.

[Use interface builder's parameters to design your look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgU2b.png)

So, in this case, defining a **titleColor** and a **backgroundColor** in your view setup is not relevant, since it's hardcoded.

If instead, you want to display a custom look to your button - like rounded corner - in your storyboard, you could use the **@IBInspectable** keyword to add new properties in interface builder.

```
@IBDesignable
class DefaultButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

By doing this, you can edit and see your view with a nice render in your storyboard!

[Custom properties directly in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WIbQ.png)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Because there will be a lot of buttons with the same style, I don't want always specify these style parameters in IB. That's purpose of creating of custom UIButton class.